# Album image cover and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am developing an app that show all album image covers. But it crashes with this error:

```
11-10 18:08:48.148  16187-16187/com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbums E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbums, PID: 16187
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1459276 byte allocation with 421736 free bytes and 411KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:1230)
            at com.xrobot.andrew.musictest2.SongAdapter.getView(SongAdapter.java:73)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
            at android.widget.ListView.correctTooLow(ListView.java:1484)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:676)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5036)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4584)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Partial code in the onCreate method:

```
...
while(...){
   String thisCover = getCoverArtPath(cursor.getLong(6), getApplicationContext());
   songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisPath, thisDuration, thisCover));
}
SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songList);
...
```

Code that I use to get the album image cover:

```
private static String getCoverArtPath(long albumId, Context context) {
    Cursor albumCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(albumId)},
            null
    );
    boolean queryResult = albumCursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = null;
    if (queryResult) {
        result = albumCursor.getString(0);
    }
    albumCursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Layout AlbumCover :

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/song_cover"
        android:scaleType = "fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/note"
        android:background="#171717"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />
```

getView in the Adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout)songInf.inflate
                (R.layout.song_layout, parent, false);
        ImageView coverView = (ImageView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_cover);

        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);

        if (Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover()) != null) {
            Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover());
            coverView.setImageDrawable(img);
        }

        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have tryed glide as suggested, but I still get the same error:

```
    if (Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover()) != null) {
        Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(currSong.getCover());
        Glide.with(mContext).load("").placeholder(img).override(50,50).into(coverView);
    }
```

This is the new error:

```
11-11 11:05:55.866  11120-11120/com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbumsE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xrobot.andrew.musicalbums, PID: 11120
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

Comment: Get the proper size of your image. Use glide for loading your images. Your image is too large.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Done, but I still get the error. See the EDIT section above :)

Comment: What's the resolution of your image? You image size is still too large.